# How to use Custom Labels in Custom Button or Link

Tags: community, custom-button, url, customlabel

I'm new to salesforce,
Is there any way to use a Custom Label in URL

`https://developer--uat.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Report/00O0w000000ZLryEAG/view?fv0={!Service_Provider__c.Name}`

Instead of **https://developer--uat.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Report**

how to use **custom labels** here ..!
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's likely that you want to use Custom Metadata for this instead of Custom Labels. As per  documentation `Custom labels are custom text values that can be translated into any language that Salesforce supports.`. Are you intending to translate the name of the provider in other languages?

Answer (score 0):

Custom labels cannot be used in Custom buttons or links. However, they can be used in URL type fields set via default values (formula editor), Workflow field updates or triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference label in Custom Button or Link.
In your custom button, you actually **do not** need to specify the domain name. So below works:

```
/lightning/r/Report/00O0w000000ZLryEAG/view?fv0={!Service_Provider__c.Name}
```

What you need to make as variable is the report ID. You can use Custom Setting (Hierarchy type) so that you can reference it in the Custom Button/Link.

Let say your custom setting name is `Report_ID__c` and the field is `MyReport__c`, then:

```
/lightning/r/Report/{!$Setup.Report_ID__c.MyReport__c}/view?fv0={!Service_Provider__c.Name}
```